# How to submit valid XML in a POST request body to an ASP.NET Core Web API that consumes XML?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-core

I've installed the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Xml` and set it up as follows in `ConfigureServices()`:

```
services.AddMvc().AddXmlSerializerFormatters();
```

Now, I've created a simple Web API as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
[Consumes("application/json", new string[]{"application/xml"})]
public ActionResult<string> OnPost([FromBody] ZapScan scan)
{
    return scan.ToString();
}
```

that accepts a `ZapScan` through model binding:

```
public class ZapScan
{
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public bool Priority { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"url={Url}, priority={Priority}\n";
    }
}
```

However, whatever XML I send from Postman is rejected, e.g:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<zapscan>
    <url>http://www.example.cm</url>
    <priority>false</priority>
</zapscan>
```

results in:

```
{"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1","title":"One or more validation errors occurred.","status":400,"traceId":"|f16a42f4-4c8f4678c6f84eb7.","errors":{"":["An error occurred while deserializing input data."]}}
```

How to properly format XML in a POST request body to a ASP.NET Web API that consumes XML?

Comment: IMHO the XML does not match the properties of the class associated to it. The deserialization could be failing because "Url" != "url" and "Priority" != "priority".

Comment: Fixing the case of the XML doesn't fix the issue :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your XML is invalid. You have two opening `<zapscan>` tags and no closing tag.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<zapscan>
    <url>http://www.example.cm</url>
    <priority>false</priority>
<zapscan> <-- this needs to be a closing tag
```

Additionally you have an issue with casing, as already covered in the comments.

Comment: @OwnPauling - thanks! But why is casing a problem for XML, when it doesn't matter for JSON? Also, do you know how to provide an enum value not by its integer value, but by its name in JSON/XML?